# Select distinct count after count?

Tags: sql

I'll cut right to the chase: I have a select I'm currently writing with a rather lengthy where clause, what I want to do is calculate percentages.

So what I need is the count of all results and then my each distinct counts.

```
SELECT distinct count(*) 
FROM mytable 
WHERE mywhereclause 
ORDER BY columnIuseInWhereClause
```

works fine for getting each individual values, but I want to avoid doing something like

```
Select (Select count(*) from mytable WHERE mywhereclause),
       distinct count(*) 
FROM mytable 
WHERE mywhereclause
```

because I'd be using the same where-clause twice which just seems unnecessary.

This is for OracleDB but I'm only using standard SQL syntax, nothing database specific if I can help it.

Thanks for any ideas.

Edit:
Sample Data

```
__ID__,__someValue__
  1   |      A      
  2   |      A
  3   |      B
  4   |      C
```

I want the occurances of A, B, C as numbers as well as the overall count.

```
__CountAll__,__ACounts__,__BCounts__,__CCounts__
     4      |     2     |     1     |     1
```

So I can get to

```
   100%     |    50%    |    25%    |    25%
```

That last part I can probably figure out on my own. Excuse my lack of experience or even logic thinking, it's early in the morning. ;)

Edit2:
I do have written a query that works but is clumsy and long as all holy heck, this one is for trying with group by.

Comment: Your first query doesn't make much sense, and the second one even less... What exactly are you trying to do? Add some sample table data and the expected result (as well formatted text.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `case` expressions to do conditional counting:

```
select count(*) as CountAll,
       count(case when someValue = 'A' then 1 end) as ACounts,
       count(case when someValue = 'B' then 1 end) as BCounts,
       count(case when someValue = 'C' then 1 end) as CCounts
FROM mytable 
WHERE mywhereclause
```

Wrap it up in a derived table to do the % part easy:

```
select 100,
       ACounts * 100 / CountAll,
       BCounts * 100 / CountAll,
       CCounts * 100 / CountAll
from
(
    select count(*) as CountAll,
           count(case when someValue = 'A' then 1 end) as ACounts,
           count(case when someValue = 'B' then 1 end) as BCounts,
           count(case when someValue = 'C' then 1 end) as CCounts
    FROM mytable 
    WHERE mywhereclause
) dt
```

Comment: Very neat, I didn't know anything about the case thing. My "clumsy and long as all holy heck" query is basically like this only the derrived table is constructed from individual SELECT COUNT(*)s. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select count(*) as CountAll, 
       count(distinct SomeColumn) as CoundDistinct -- The DISTINCT goes inside the brackets
from myTable
where SomeOtherColumn = 'Something'
```

Comment: I am bit late to answer :( it's a answer with good understanding. +1 for you

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative using window function:

```
with data_table(ID, some_value)
AS
(SELECT 1,'A' UNION ALL
 SELECT 2,'A' UNION ALL
 SELECT 3,'B' UNION ALL
 SELECT 4,'C' 
)

SELECT DISTINCT [some_value],
       COUNT([some_value]) OVER () AS Count_All, 
       COUNT([some_value]) OVER (PARTITION BY [some_value]) AS 'Counts' FROM [data_table]
ORDER BY [some_value]
```

The advantage is that you don't have to hard-code your [some_value]